# Adding UDP Over IPSEC Packets in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

New-bie to Linux. Have a requirement to Tunnel Received IPSec Packets inside UDP. Thought of doing it like this...

1. Use the mmaped version of libpcap to Capture the Packets from NIC and send to User Space.
2. After getting the Packets in UserSpace; using RAW Sockets for adding UDP Header over the IPSEC Payload.

was this the effective approach of achieving this ? OR any better way ???

Looking forward for the reply !

Answer (score 0):

You might just copy the IPSEC packets to the AF_INET/SOCK_DGRAM socket.
Not sure if splice() system call works with both sockets, but if it does - splice()
would be better due to no copying between kernel/user space performed

Comment: Thanks Man.
If My understanding was correct; I need to create a Listening Socket for the UDP Port 500 & another Socket of Type SOCK_DGRAM. Then; use the splice system call to copy the information between these Sockets. Was that correct ??

-Thnx,
KSV